# How to create the backend to multiple user types displayed in radio buttons? Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails. I took an idea from another user when creating multiple user types using STI. So, at this point, I have two user types, teachers and students, and they all are shown as 
Class Teacher < User
Class Student < User
I used Devise which automatically create a signup (registrations path) and a user model.

```
    <div class="authform">
    <%= form_for @users(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
```

And then skipping ahead to the radio buttons:

```
    <div>
      <%= "I am a..." %>
      <%= radio_button_tag(:user, "student") %>
      <%= label_tag(:student, "student") %>
      <%= radio_button_tag(:user, "teacher") %>
      <%= label_tag(:teacher, "teacher") %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', :class => 'button right' %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

How do I attach this to backend and user types? Here is my user.rb

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  def skip_confirmation!
   self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc
  end

  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
  #:confirmable, 
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 

  def to_param
     username
  end
end
```

And here is my user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    authorize @user
    redirect_to 'classrooms#index'
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # authorize @user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

Comment: So your question is how to send data from `radio` button to rails controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do.

If you were trying to send data which is from radio button, you can add a `form_tag`.

Before that, we should probably define our `controller`.

For example, I define a `create_user_type` in **user_controller.rb**

```
 def create_user_type
   byebug ## it will bind your termianl and help you to see the parameter
 end
```

Then edit **routes.rb**, add this line.

```
post 'users/create_user_type' => 'users/create_user_type'
```

Finally, change your **form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag users_create_user_type_url do |f| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:user, "student") %>
  <%= label_tag(:student, "student") %>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:user, "teacher") %>
  <%= label_tag(:teacher, "teacher") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Save!"%>
<% end %>
```

So, in your browser, you can see this [image]

After you click the save button, you should notice your terminal is binding.

Now you can print the `params` to see what's the data from the `radio` button.

[image]